# Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'. error in react-native

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, npm, android-emulator

I got this error on react-native every time.

Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to install on any devices.

How can i fix this?